# MP4 videos served from a PHP script on IIS (Azure) only plays audio with Safari

Tags: php, azure, iis, safari, html5-video

I'm trying to serve a mp4 video from a PHP script. In all browsers works without problem, but when I try with Safari the video plays only with sound (without image).

The problem happens only with Safari and IIS, I tried with Safari and Apache and works fine.

If I try view the video directly from the server (without the PHP script) it works perfectly.

The code of the PHP script:

```
public function video() {
    $params = Manager::getParams();

    if (array_key_exists(2, $params)) {
        $filename = $params[2];

        $path = VIDEOS_FOLDER . $filename;
        $mime = 'video/mp4';

        $this->get_file($path, $mime);
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect params";
    }
}

private function get_file($path, $mime) {
    // Clears the cache and prevent unwanted output
    ob_clean();
    session_write_close();
    @ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
    //@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

    $size = filesize($path); // The size of the file
    // Send the content type header
    header('Content-type: ' . $mime);

    // Check if it's a HTTP range request
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        // Parse the range header to get the byte offset
        $ranges = array_map(
                'intval', // Parse the parts into integer
                explode('-', // The range separator
                        substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 6) // Skip the `bytes=` part of the header
                )
        );

        // If the last range param is empty, it means the EOF (End of File)
        if (!$ranges[1]) {
            $ranges[1] = $size - 1;
        }

        // Send the appropriate headers
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Length: ' . ($ranges[1] - $ranges[0])); // The size of the range
        // Send the ranges we offered
        header(
                sprintf(
                        'Content-Range: bytes %d-%d/%d', // The header format
                        $ranges[0], // The start range
                        $ranges[1], // The end range
                        $size // Total size of the file
                )
        );

        // It's time to output the file
        $f = fopen($path, 'rb'); // Open the file in binary mode
        $chunkSize = 8192; // The size of each chunk to output
        // Seek to the requested start range
        fseek($f, $ranges[0]);

        // Start outputting the data
        while (true) {
            // Check if we have outputted all the data requested
            if (ftell($f) >= $ranges[1]) {
                break;
            }

            // Output the data
            echo fread($f, $chunkSize);

            // Flush the buffer immediately
            @ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    } else {
        // It's not a range request, output the file anyway
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

        // Read the file
        @readfile($path);

        // and flush the buffer
        @ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

My problem becomes when I play the video on Safari with IIS server, it just play the sound.

I added the following to the web.config:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using `<video>` tag in front end, and the inside `source` is your PHP script which serves the mp4 video?

Comment: Thanks for the response @GaryLiu-MSFT, this is the code I'm using:
`<video id="lessonVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%"  data-setup='{}'>
            <source src="{WEB_PATH}/files/video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>`

where /files/video/ is the script and video.mp4 the filename as an argument (so yes, is like you said)